# dataLayer in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community, dom, tag-manager, gtm

Can someone tell me how can I access DOM dataLayer in lightning component controller?
I'm using like this but its not pushing into DOM dataLayer

```
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push
    ({        
            'event': 'testEvent',
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do it from the Lightning Component itself, but you can from the community page (HEAD Markup).
I'm not sure if this is the correct way but seems to be doing something.

1. in the Lightning component controller (or helper) add the following script to the function/event you want to tag.

```
document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("updateGTMdataLayer", { "detail" : { event: "[eventName]"} }));
```

This will send an event that can be caught by the community page.
Identify the event (ex: updateGTMdataLayer) and create a JSON with the details you want to pass.

2. Edit the community HEAD Markup with the following script:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('updateGTMdataLayer', function(e) {
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
            'event': e.detail.event
        });
    });
</script>

Catch the event sent by the Lightning Component, parse the JSON and update the DOM dataLayer.

I hope it makes some sense. :)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, not directly. The global window object typically found in the DOM is replaced with a [SecureWindow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer) implementation. As such, you can set a dataLayer in your component, but it won't be globally visible. I presume you're trying to do this for Google Tag Management; you would need to import that library into your component and use whatever methods are available to manipulate the data layer.